# Removing The Trailing Slash from a directory in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, slash

The following is my directory structure

```
Root/
    index.php
    contact.php
    projects.php
                /index.php
                /project1.php
                /project2.php
```

I have rewrites in place to remove the .php extension from all file names. It works perfectly fine and I can access `www.website.com/projects/project2.php` from `www.website.com/projects/project2`

I also want to be able to access `www.website.com/projects/index.php` as `www.website.com/projects`

I have managed to write a rule which rewrites the url to `www.website.com/projects/` when i type `www.website.com/projects`

However, I am not being able to get rid of the last trailing slash.

Please note that I do not really understand much of this. Most of it is from what I have found on the internet. I have looked around a lot but not got anything to work till now.

Here is the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^projects$ /projects/index.php [L,E=LOOP:1]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this: `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by [mod_dir and the DirectorySlash directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). It will automatically 301 redirect requests for a directory that's missing the trailing slash. This fixes an information disclosure security concern (described in the above link) which lists the directory contents even when there's an index file (e.g. `index.php`). So if you turn this functionality off, *be very careful about your directories*. If you've got directory indexing turned off, then that's not so much of a concern.

You can turn of directory slashes using:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

You can turn off directory indexing using the Options:

```
Options -Indexes
```

And then, you need to have your projects rule **before** your php extension rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^projects$ /projects/index.php [L,E=LOOP:1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: 403 forbidden is appearing when DirectorySlash is Off

Answer (score 1):

This come in handy if you want to remove trailing slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The explanation for this rule is the same as it is for when we want to add a trailing slash, just in reverse. We can also specify specific directories that we don't want apply this rule to.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !directory/(.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Source](https://www.crucialhosting.com/knowledgebase/htaccess-apache-rewrites-examples)